# Bind Variable "usrname" is NOT DECLARED Issues - SQL Developer settings

Tags: oracle, variables, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a series of scripts which use the below code to insert/update entries to an oracle DB. The code runs correctly in my instance of SQL Developer (4.0.1.14.18) however, when my colleague attempts to run it they get the below error:

Bind Variable "usrname" is NOT DECLARED
anonymous block completed

Now, having looked around I find that the SQL is Dynamic and Oracle doesn't like running it so I have to rewrite the code in EXECUTE IMMEDIATE format to get SQL developer to run it.

However, this doesn't explain why the code runs correctly from my machine and not theirs. Can anyone offer any insight as to why the application behaves differently? Is there an easier way to run the code than rewriting it? I have lots of scripts and am reluctant to redo them all.

```
define
var usrid varchar2(8)
var usrname varchar2(40)
var usremail varchar2(50)

/* define variable values */ 
exec :usrid := UPPER('k163ed41') /* usr_id -- kcl ID */
exec :usrname :=  INITCAP('John Smith') /* usr_dsc -- user name */
exec :usremail := :usrid || '@kcl.ac.uk' /* usremail_id -- user email */

/* create usermenu */ 
CREATE TABLE usermenutemptable (MEN_ID varchar2(8), MEN_DSC varchar2(40));

-- insert values to Tempemp
INSERT INTO usermenutemptable (men_id, men_dsc) VALUES (:usrid ,:usrname);

-- select * from temptable;
MERGE INTO menu s
USING (select men_id, men_dsc from usermenutemptable) t
ON (s.men_id = t.men_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET s.men_DSC = t.men_DSC
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN insert values (t.MEN_ID, t.men_DSC);
--select * from susr where usr_id = :usrid
commit;

drop table usermenutemptable;
```

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: did you colleague also use sql developer, or did they use SQL*Plus? if sql developer, what version did they run it on? and i'm assuming they executed with F5 (run as script), and like the person above asks, show us the entire error message

Comment: @OldProgrammer the error does not state a line number. The full text of the error is: Bind Variable "usrname" is NOT DECLARED anonymous block completed

Comment: @thatjeffsmithThey are running the same version or oracle SQLdeveloper as i am (4.0.1.14.18).

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Sorry, forgot to add, yes, same result with F5 or Run statement.